# Can a mark be maintained when the target is invisible?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

Can a mark from a `Fighter`, `Battlemind`, etc. be maintained when the target goes invisible?

Comment: Remember, Invisible is not the same as Hidden. Even if someone turns Invisible, everybody on the battlefield still knows where s/he is unless he successfully becomes Hidden to them.

Comment: Yeap, appreciate that there is a battlefield awareness so the target is still known to be "there".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An attacker takes a -5 penalty to attacks against an invisible target. Invisibility has no special effect on marking, just that if the marking attack requires a hit it would be harder to achieve.

Turning invisible while marked does not remove it from you. Marks last either until the specified duration on the effect or until the marked target dies or falls unconscious.

Comment: @stevec - The jury is [still out](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/is-there-a-functional-purpose-to-putting-things-in-code-text-here) on formatting of special terms, but I definitely frown on highlighting of non game defined terms like marking or invisibility.

Comment: Small addend: Marks also disappear if the creature that placed the mark goes unconscious or die.